# How to remove samsung syncmaster 2243SN stand?

Tags: disassembly

I have a samsung syncmaster 2243SN monitor with simple stand. I can't remove the piece connecting the round base with monitor, it seems locked. The online user guide is useless, as it only covers removing the round base and using vesa interface (I think for hooking the monitor onto wall). I tried pulling, pushing, sweaving, I even unscrewed two screws from other side of the connector, but they seem to only hold the connector intact.

And help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two or three stand options for that model, but from the last round of Samsungs I used with "simple stands", they were a PITA to remove; so I'll assume that's what you have.

The hollow connector shaft that goes from the round base to the monitor itself, is press fit (by the user during unpacking) onto a hinged piece that's attached to the monitor. Then the round base is screwed (with a thumb-screw) to the connector shaft.

Unscrew and remove the round base.

Look up into the connector shaft.  There is probably two small plastic tabs accessible from inside the connector shaft.  To release the shaft, both tabs need to be pushed apart (maybe inward?, it's been a while), and held out of the way while the shaft is wiggled off a millimeter or two at a time.

Again, it's a PITA, so expect plenty of fidgeting and wiggling to get both tabs released at the same time so that the connector piece can be pulled/wiggled/worked off of the monitor.

A couple small slot screw drivers can help with triggering/holding the tabs.  Having a second pair of hands to pull while holding the tabs can help as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung 2233SW model has two tabs/pins/swivel pieces that **DO NOT PRESS IN** as they are solid. There are also two "hooks". The method I used is a **PERMANENT** removal of the base. Using a drill motor and drill bit, drill one pin until weakened or gone. Then holding the monitor, strike the swivel base to the side away from the drilled out or weakened pin. Small thin plastic catches that hold the hooks will break out (see red arrows and circles) and the swivel will then pull out. "Wrestle" the rubber cup like part out by hand.

- The upper left photo shows drilled pin.
- Lower left photo shows one pin drilled away and the hooks on top.
- Upper right photo shows the bottom of the slots broken out.
- Bottom right photo shows the rubber piece removed.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the base comes off simply by pulling it straight out.  I know, that sounds really dumb and simple, but it works.  The base is actually held onto the monitor by a metal plate and friction.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with old SyncMaster 2494's that I can't seem to get rid of is somewhere between the two other answers. All I have to do is to remove the screw under the circular base. Then use a flat head to pry between the metal plate and the monitor while pulling the remaining part of the base side to side.